# How can we compare an encrypted number with a normal number?

Tags: encryption, machine-learning

I am currently doing a project on privacy preserving encryption using a k-means system and the Paillier encryption algorithm (homomorphic algorithm). I have to send an image of a skin disease to the server as an encrypted image.

To do this, k-means is applied on the encrypted image and the image is sent to the respective party with k-means already applied. The decryption happens on the party side.

However in the k-means algorithm itself, I have to compare an encrypted pixel value of the image to a normal number, and this is where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Pailler is PKC. take negative, send server let it add, decrypt?

Answer (score 1):

If this is not performed under the encrypted version of the plaintext on the semi-honest party there is a problem.

Assume that there is a method $f(m,c)$ return $T$ if the values are same and $F$ if the values are not same. So you can compare a plaintext with a ciphertext.

With the same way you did, an attacker can test any number to reveal the value.

```
   for i in range(plaintext):
       if F(i,c):
          break
```

So this must be as follows;

- negate the value,
- encrypt it with the Paillier,
- Sent it to the server.
- the server calculates the summation,
- the server returns the result.

If there are more than one k-means on the server, and, actually, you are trying to perform

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key_mean = query
```

you need to apply a different method.

Comment: Hi, can u please elaborate it a bit, I am not able to understand how this solves my problem.

Comment: which part do you want

Comment: Actually u have just not given the answer to my question.

Comment: @aniketagarwal, As I understand you have a database uploaded the images encrypted with AES or similar and  their k-means encrypted with Paillier. You want to query by the k-means, right?